# No change but re-rendered

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count up!</button>
            <ChildComponent />
        </div>
    )
}

const ChildComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('render!');
        return () => console.log('unmounted...');
    });

    return (
        <div>children</div>
    )
};


export default Test;
```

Press the "Count up!" button.
log was output.

```
unmounted...
render!
```

ChildComponent is unchanged.
But rendered again.

why?
And how to prevent re-rendering?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it re render because it's nested in a component that re render to prevent a nested component re render use React.memo()

```
const Test = () => {
    const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count up! {count} </button>
            <ChildComponent />
        </div>
    )
}

const ChildComponent = React.memo(() => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('render!');
        return () => console.log('unmounted...');
    });

    return (
        <div>children</div>
    )
});


export default Test;
```

you can read more about [memo](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: In that case, if you pass a static array to props, it will be redrawn.
`<ChildComponent staticArray={[ 1, 2, 3]} />`
Is the array always considered updated?

Comment: the component wrapped in react memo it updates only on its own state or props update

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent state is updated, the whole component will be re-rendered, include its children too, no matter if its children are changed or unchanged. You can use `React.memo()` to prevent your components from re-rendering. `useCallback` and `useMemo` can be used to memoize too.

See more here: [How to memoize in React](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/how-to-memoize-in-react-3d20cbcd2b6e).